# ¿Como hacer que un archivo html se habilite para usar razor?

Tags: c#, html5, razor

Trabajo en un proyecto Windows Froms, Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tengo una plantilla en html para poder crear un pdf esta plantilla tiene parámetros que debo de pasarselos para poder crear el reporte.

Estoy usando [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

Lo que hago es lo siguiente

```
private void btnDeserealizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pathXml = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EsquemaXML");
        var pathFacturaXml = Path.Combine(pathXml, "Factura_001-100-000000016_1006.6_ROMAN CHIRIBOGA VERONICA ISABEL.xml");

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (factura));
        var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(pathFacturaXml);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var factura = (factura) serializer.Deserialize(ms);

            //MessageBox.Show($"{factura.infoTributaria.ambiente} {factura.infoTributaria.razonSocial}" +
            //                $" {factura.infoFactura.razonSocialComprador}", @"Aviso");


            var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile("templateKey", typeof (FacturaViewModel), new FacturaViewModel
            {
                Ambiente = factura.infoTributaria.ambiente,
                RazonSocial = factura.infoTributaria.razonSocial,
                RazonSocialComprador = factura.infoFactura.razonSocialComprador
            });
        } 
    }
```

Lo que hago es lo siguiente, como la información que le voy a pasar a la plantilla esta en archivos XML lo serialize a clase y facilmente los puedo obtener.
Y ahí es donde aplico Razor tengo un modelo para pasarle los datos de la deserealización, el problema es ahora como se lo paso a la plantilla.

Lo que se me ocurrio fue cambiarle la extensión a la plantilla por cshtml para poder instanciar el modelo.

```
@model CrearReportePDF.Models.FacturaViewModel
{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="535"  valign="top" style="font-size:6;font-family:'Calibri';color:black;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td  valign="top">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td  width="276" valign="top">
                                    <table border="0"  style="border-color:red;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td  valign="top"><img src="@logo" height="90" width="230"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td  valign="top">                                              
                                                <span style='font-size:12.0pt;'><b>@razonSocial @Html.</b></span> <br/>
                                                <span style='font-size:9.0pt;'>@nombreComercial</span>  <br/><br/>
                                                <span style='font-size:12.0pt;'><b>R.U.C.:</b> </span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;'> @ruc</span> <br/><br/>
                                                <span><b>Dir. Matriz: </b> </span><span> @dirMatriz</span> <br/>
                                                <span><b>Dir. Sucursal: </b> </span><span> @dirSucursal</span> <br/><br/>
                                                <span><b>OBLIGADO A LLEVAR CONTABILIDAD: </b> </span><span> @obligadoContabilidad</span><br/>
                                                <span><b>CONTRIBUYENTE ESPECIAL: </b> </span><span> @contribuyenteEspecial</span><br/>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
```

Pero no me reconoce el @model me imagino que pudiera usar un ViewBag.
Mi pregunta sería ¿Como puedo comunicar razor con la plantilla?

¿Como se aplicar el engine para que los una, igual a como lo hace asp.net mvc?

Saludos!

Comment: Para la declaracion de tu variable usa sin corchetes:@model CrearReportePDF.Models.FacturaViewModel dentro de la declaracion de tu pagina usa @Model.Ambiente estas usando minusculas al principio y tu prop inicia en mayuscula

Comment: @MiguelZarate Claro cuando agrego el `@model` para instanciar el modelo no me reconoce ´@model´ y esta correcto la escritura para obtener su propiedades uso @Model pero primero no me reconoce el ´@model´ y en consecuencia no me sirve el @Model no tengo intellisense y eso que cambie la extención a cshtml, el tema es solucionar `@model´ me imagino que el error pasa por que no le he dicho a la vista que debe trabajar con C#?

Comment: ademas de la extension en propiedades agrega:  BuildAction = EmbeddedResource o crea una pagina cshtml junto con el modelo y agreaga tu codigo html con las propiedades del modelo, .Si la vista no 've' la libreria del modelo no podras compilar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas definir el `@model` para usar una clase como view, solo analiza los ejemplos

[Template basics](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/doc/TemplateBasics.md)

veras que utiliza la clase `Person` en un template que viene del string con el `@Model` y no se necesito definir la clase

```
string template = "<div>Hello @Model.Name</div>";
var model = new Person { Name = "Matt" };

string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "key", typeof(Person), model);
```

porque no es un `cshtml` lo que usas sino un simple `html` que lees como string

Comment: Gracias Leandro!

Answer (score 0):

No puedes para razor tu pagina html simple, debe tener extesion cshtml.

En el comentario agregado:
  usa la declaracion en cshtml:
@model CrearReportePDF.Models.FacturaViewModel
en la declaracion dentro de la pagina

### @Model.Ambiente // con mayuscula al inicio

Ahora si lo que buscas es sustitucion de variables simples en una pagina html le debes dar un trato como cadena de texto:

```
html:
<head></head>
<body>{titulo}</body>


//sustituiremos la variable titulo en tu codigo declaras una clase auxiliar y agregas el siguiente metodo:
 private static string Format(string value, IDictionary<string, object> data)
        {
            foreach (var key in data.Keys)
                value = value.Replace($"{{{key}}}", (data[key] ?? Empty).ToString());

            return value;
        }



 public string generarHmtlPlantilla()
{

string htmlPlatilla= cargarPlantilla(pathPlantilla);
//cargar plantilla tu la debes implementar es facil solo lo lees desde donde la guardes.
var tituloPagina="Ejemplo Uno";
string htmlPlantillaSalida= Format(htmlPlantilla,new {} tituloPlantilla
                            //separas por coma las demas variables
                          };

return htmlPlantillaSalida;

}
```

Listo, es recomendable usar razor pero si no puedes pues utilizas lo escrito lineas arriba

Nota:
en cshtml casi siempre marca un error en la pagina pero si compila todo esta bien .La escritura en la declaracion es @model  MiModelo la referencia despues es @Model.MiPropiedad revisa que en las propiedades de tu documento este BuildAction = EmbeddedResource

Comment: Gracias lo tomare como segunda alternativa se ve interesante.

Comment: Hice lo que me recomiendas de la propiedad de la plantilla cshtml pero igual no me reconoce el @model me parece que esa plantilla no sabe que tiene que trabajar con razor también he compilado.

Comment: Crea una vista y agrega el modelo usando el asistente, asi ya dejaras que tu solucion agregue las referencias necesarias y ya solo modificas el html que necesites.

Comment: El detalle es que estoy trabajando en Windows Forms, pero si tengo entendido que con Razor Engine se puede hacer que trabaje como lo hace asp.net mvc el engine es capaz de unir ambos el problemilla es que no se como hacer esa parte.